# Code optimisation / better way to manipulate class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

I have this code for a long time and I wonder if there is a short or better way to do this. We have matching Services and Workers and this code finds the matching service for some worker.

```rb
def FooWorker
  def service_klass
    self.class.name
        .then(&:underscore)
        .then { |name| name.split('_') }
        .then { |name| name[0...-1] << :service }
        .then { |name| name.join('_') }
        .classify
        .safe_constantize
  end
end

FooWorker.service_klass # -> FooService
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just replace `Worker` with `Service`?

```
def service_klass
  self.class.name.sub(/Worker\z/, 'Service').safe_constantize
end
```

Comment: Because I was afraid there would be some Worker with multiple Worker instances in name: UpdateWorkerLaterWorker. But with your flag it works just fine